# Can I replace the LED in this bathroom light fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led, bulb

I'm remodeling a bathroom and have a light fixture where one of the 3 lights is dimmer than the others.  After taking off the glass -- I'm seeing the bulb pictured below.  It looks like its secured by 2 screws on either side.

1. Is this bulb REPLACEABLE or do I need to replace the entire light
   fixture?
2. Does anyone recognize what TYPE of bulb that is?

[image: Bathroom Light w/ LED Bulb]

Comment: There's no such thing as a bulb with LEDs.  There's a light emitter, but it will outlive all of us.  There is also drive electronics, and that is where the issue lies.  Drive electronics are vulnerable to the effects of cost cutting.  The two tiny screws should not be tampered with.  The four? Larger screws? Maybe ok.  If the unit is delivering 120VAC to the module (driver inside module x3) then it may be sourceable.  Is there a make/model on the fixture?  Did the seller install the fixture as part of the sale or sale prep?

Comment: @dandavis I think the typical 10-year or 20-year "lifetime" for LED fixtures is based more on (a) drive electronics wearing out and (b) **average** lifetime of all the components together, than on the lifetime of the actual LEDs. There is some dimming of the actual LEDs over time, but in my experience (limited, since consumer grade LED fixtures have only been available at a reasonable price for a few years) the dimming is relatively gradual. I wouldn't be surprised if 50 years from now there are some top-quality LED fixtures installed today still producing a reasonable amount of light.

Comment: OP: you will probably have to replace all 3 lamps in order to get a match.